# How to fetch SharePoint PermMask field value using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online

Need help in fetching the SharePoint PermMask field value using Javascript for Sharepoint Online site.

Answer (score 3):

### How to get PermMask field value using SharePoint JSOM

Explicitly specify `PermMask` field in [SP.ClientContext.load method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
ctx.load(item,'PermMask');
```

**Example**

```
var listTitle = 'Documents';
var itemid = 1;

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(itemid);
ctx.load(item,'PermMask');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
        console.log('Item Effective Permissions Mask: ' + item.get_item('PermMask'));
   },
   function(sender,args){
         console.log(args.get_message());
   }
);
```

[image]