# Permission Masks

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom

Is it possible to get permission masks and type using csom?
The following web service
/_vti_bin/Permissions.asmx?op=GetPermissionCollection looks to return what I am looking for. However I can't use the following with modern authentication

I'm looking to get the following information

```
<Role RoleId="1073741826" Title="Read" Description="Can view pages and list items and download documents." PermMask="756052856929" Hidden="false" RoleOrder="128" Type="2" />
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated

**Edit**
Added screenshot for proposed answer
[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129899/how-to-fetch-sharepoint-permmask-field-value-using-javascript) if it helps.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks I did try that, but still didn't have any luck

Answer (score 0):

You can get Mask from RoleDefinition.BasePermission which does have non-public member called High and Low.

In case of Full Control Permission, it will give always fixed number i.e. 4294967295

Sample code

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreateSiteFromTemplate
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                using (ClientContext sourceSiteContext = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager("", @"", "", "").GetContext("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Template"))
                {
                    Web srcWeb = sourceSiteContext.Web;
                    sourceSiteContext.Load(srcWeb);
                    sourceSiteContext.Load(srcWeb.RoleAssignments);
                    sourceSiteContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    List lst = srcWeb.GetList(srcWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + "Shared Documents");
                    sourceSiteContext.Load(lst);
                    sourceSiteContext.Load(lst.RoleAssignments);
                    sourceSiteContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (var roleAssignment in lst.RoleAssignments)
                    {
                        var roleDefinitions = roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings;

                        sourceSiteContext.Load(roleDefinitions);
                        sourceSiteContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        foreach (var roleDefinition in roleDefinitions)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine(roleDefinition.Id);                            
                            var propertyHigh = roleDefinition.BasePermissions.GetType().GetProperty("High", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
                            var propertyLow = roleDefinition.BasePermissions.GetType().GetProperty("Low", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
                            var highValue = Convert.ToUInt32(propertyHigh.GetValue(roleDefinition.BasePermissions));
                            var LowValue = Convert.ToUInt32(propertyLow.GetValue(roleDefinition.BasePermissions));                            

                            if(LowValue == 4294967295) // In case of Full Control permission
                            {                                
                                Console.WriteLine($"Mask for {roleAssignment.PrincipalId} : -1");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Mask for {roleAssignment.PrincipalId} : {LowValue}");
                            }                            
                        }
                    }                  
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Finished");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will helpful to you

I am receiving below XML using Web Service GetPermissionCollection under _vti_bin/permissions.asmx (Not sure why you are receiving **Role** element instead of **Permission** element

```
<Permissions
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
<Permission MemberID="3" Mask="-1" MemberIsUser="False" MemberGlobal="True" GroupName="Template Owners" />
<Permission MemberID="4" Mask="138612833" MemberIsUser="False" MemberGlobal="True" GroupName="Template Visitors" />
<Permission MemberID="5" Mask="1011030767" MemberIsUser="False" MemberGlobal="True" GroupName="Template Members" />
<Permission MemberID="11" Mask="1011028719" MemberIsUser="True" MemberGlobal="False" UserLogin="i:0#.f|membership|administrator@contoso.onmicrosoft.com" />
```

And according to that I am receiving correct Mask view using CSOM code as well.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try on Monday and let you know

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I've given it a go and the perm mask doesn't appear to match these values here for example: <Role RoleId="1073741826" Title="Read" Description="Can view pages and list items and download documents." PermMask="756052856929" Hidden="false" RoleOrder="128" Type="2" />

Comment: So in this case which value you are receiving in High and Low property?

Comment: I've updated the question with a screenshot of output. Thanks

Comment: When I am calling GetPermissionCollection Web Service I am receiving following response

<Permissions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/"><Permission MemberID="3" Mask="-1" MemberIsUser="False" MemberGlobal="True" GroupName="Template Owners" /></Permissions>

I am not sure why you are receiving Role XML node.. are you get Web Permission or List Permission? And do you have custom permission level?

Comment: Can you provide exact web service URL and method which you are using?

Comment: GetPermissionCollection Web Service has all the information I require, but I can't use modern authentication with it. This is why I'm trying to get it via csom,

Comment: What I have mentioned in previous comment that I am calling same GetPermissionCollection web service but I am receiving different result, I am not receiving <Role> node but I am receiving <Permissions> node there I am also getting Mask, 

And according to that code which I shared it working fine for me

Comment: Would it be possible to share a screen shot of your output? Are you running this against a a SharePoint online site? Thanks

Comment: Yes. I will share my screenshot on Monday

Comment: I have added output of web service call that I have checked and yes I am using SharePoint Online and trying to get Library permissions.

Comment: Sorry in the delay in getting back to you, can you add a screenshot of the output from your code snippet using csom please?